# Spliton in Dapper, ASP NET Core

Tags: asp.net-mvc, split, dapper

```cs
string query = @"SELECT
    l.LoginId,
    l.Email,
    un.UserNameId,
    un.Name,
    un.CPF,
    un.CellPhone,
    ga.GroupId,
    ga.Name
    FROM Tb_Login l
    INNER JOIN Tb_UserName un
        ON un.IdLogin = l.LoginId
    INNER JOIN Tb_GroupAccess ga
        ON ga.GroupId = l.IdGroupAccess
    WHERE un.IdLogin = @Id
        AND l.IdStatusLogin = 1";

var obj = _connection.Query<EmployeeResponse, Login, UserName, GroupAccess,  EmployeeResponse>(
    sql: query,
    map: (loginResponse, login, userName, groupAcess) =>
    {
        loginResponse.Login = login;
        loginResponse.UserName = userName;
        loginResponse.GroupAccess = groupAcess;

        return loginResponse;
    }, 
    splitOn: "UserNameId,GroupId",
    param: new
    {
        Id = request.IdEmployee
    }
    ).FirstOrDefault();
```

This code is returning:

> System.ArgumentException: 'Multi-map error: splitOn column 'UserNameId' was not found - please ensure your splitOn parameter is set and in the correct order Arg_ParamName_Name'

I'm having problems trying to do this spliton.

Comment: The first `EmployeeResponse` in the query shouldn't be there. It should say `_connection.Query<Login, UserName, GroupAccess,  EmployeeResponse>` meaning: Map to Login, UserName and GroupAccess, return an EmployeeResponse. There is nothing in the query that can be mapped directly to EmployeeResponse.

Answer (score 0):

As I stated in my comment: The first EmployeeResponse in the query shouldn't be there. It should say `_connection.Query<Login, UserName, GroupAccess, EmployeeResponse>` meaning: Map to Login, UserName and GroupAccess, return an EmployeeResponse. There is nothing in the query that can be mapped directly to EmployeeResponse

Therefore you also need to create the employee response yourself, so the code becomes something like:

```cs
var obj = _connection.Query<Login, UserName, GroupAccess,  EmployeeResponse>(
    sql: query,
    map: (login, userName, groupAccess) =>
    {
        return new EmployeeResponse {
            Login = login;
            UserName = userName;
            GroupAccess = groupAccess};
    }, 
    splitOn: "UserNameId,GroupId",
    param: new
    {
        Id = request.IdEmployee
    }
    ).FirstOrDefault();
```